# testing a website after making changes to many pages on the site

Tags: php, testing, html

I have a lot of .php and/or .php files on my site. **Is there a way to go through each site/page and work out which ones(if any) have errors in the console in the broswer?**

More generally, I am looking at making a change to many pages on my site and I am just wondering what is the best way to automate the test process to see that I did not break anything with the changes I made.

Note: the errors in the console in the broswer, will give me errors, but it would not show errors that only the human eye could detect.

Comment: You can check error_log file for error OR can test your code online for errors.

Comment: @RahulMukati I currently check each page in the broswer and check the console to check for errors. I am wondering is there a better/script to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered an automated testing framework?

http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2012/11/03/testing-php-web-applications-with-cucumber/

Repetitively manually testing ur site is not fun.